# URL redirection to subdomain without changing URL in address

Tags: redirect

I am new to Linux and want to use .htaccess or proxy for the URL redirection leaving URL unchanged with apache2.

Now i want to redirect my main domain http://example.com/test to my subdomain http://test.example.com without changing the URL in address bar.

Kindly help me in giving me some guidelines with .htaccess or proxy or some other..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the URL to change you either need a Reverse proxy set-up between the two virtual hosts / domains, or if  example.com is just an alias, same IP and served from the same Apache virtual host, you could use an internal rewrite. More info [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278439/using-htaccess-redirect-301-without-changing-url-in-address-bar)

your can also try this. for more infor go [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161394/redirect-domain-com-to-domain-com-category-without-changing-the-url-in-address-b)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(index.\php)?$ /category [L]
```

This only works for requests for http://domain.com/ or http://domain.com/index.php, and you'd get served the content at http://domain.com/category without changing the URL in the address bar. You can probably even lose the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$` [NC] line if you don't need it.

there is also a helpful resource [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3323670.htm)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
######## example.com ######## 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*example.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond /www/quux-foo.com/www/root/v1%{REQUEST_URI} -d 
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*quux-foo.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/v1/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*example.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond /www/quux-foo.com/www/root/v1%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR] 
RewriteCond /www/quux-foo.com/www/root/v1%{REQUEST_URI} -d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*example.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v1/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v1/index.php [L] 
######## example.com ########
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response mayur, i want http://example.com/test to server the content of http://test.example.com/

For that i need a redirection code. I am able to redirect the webiste by placing a index.php in the category folder with the header code in it. But i dont what URL to be changed. It has to show the URL as http://example.com/test